# Nice way to return 'default' object using generics

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Suppose I have a class that is parent for other classes and contains boolean flag indicating something went wrong during processing. For example:

```
class BaseClass 
{
    private bool error;
    ....
}
```

The children of the class are used in the processing.
It is used by a classes implementing a service interface:

```
public interface MyService 
{
   public ClassA execute1();
   public ClassB execute2();
   public List<ClassC> execute3(); 
}
```

`ClassA`, `ClassB` and `ClassC` extend from `BaseClass`.
The instances of the classes implementing the above interface are used in other class being a Spring `@Service`, there is a list of the services:

```
List<MyService> services;
```

in the service class there's also a method to call instances of the MyService implementations in a few running concurrently threads. The signature is

```
public <T> List<T> callServices(Function<MyService, T> callback)
```

My question is - how inside callServices method return empty object of ClassA, ClassB or List with the error flag set?

I thought about something like:

```
public <T extends BaseClass> List<T> callServices(Function<MyService, T> callback)
```

but this is not suitable for `List<ClassC>`.

We do not know the exact type and there is erasure. The problem is with the `List<ClassC>`. What I thought about is to pass an extra parameter to the method with the error flag present, but I wanted to know if there is some other, more generic way to do that.

Comment: You may use the `where` constraint but what you are trying is very odd. What exactly is your goal?

Comment: Why is `error` private? If it were `internal` or `public` it could be set. If services need to know whether there's been an error then that information should be public.

Answer (score 0):

```
where T: new()
```

And put the error initialization in the default constructor. The deserialization will clear the error. Sometimes this works even if T isn't being deserialized.